# dynamically expand tags

Tags: css

I'm having problems with setting the div and body tags to dynamically expand over the inner contain.

Here is the HTML and CSS that I'm using, it is a little longer.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" />
<title></title>
</head>
<style>
body, p, b, ul, li, div
{
padding:0;
margin:0;
border:0;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
body
{
background:white;
}

.clearfix {
    min-height: 1px;
}
.clearfix:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    font-size: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
}
#searchform
{
position:absolute;
height:110px;
clear:both;
}
#b2_sbox_middle
{
width:980px;
height:99px;
background:url('img.jpg') repeat-x;
border:1px solid #00CCCC;
}
#b2_inner_sf
{
margin-top:10px;
}
#sf_ch_container
{
clear:both;
margin-left:27px;
font-size:18px;
}

#sf_ch_formtitle
{
float:left;
width:202px;
font-size:18px;
text-align:left;
}
#sf_ch_stype
{
float:left;
}
.stype
{

    float:left;
    margin-left:27px;
    text-align: left;
}
</style>
<body>
<div align="center" class="clearfix">
<div id="searchform" align="center" style="top:105px; width:980px; margin-left:-490px; left:50%;" class="clearfix">
<div id="b2_sbox_middle">
<div id="b2_inner_sf" class="clearfix" style="border:0px solid;">
<div id="sf_ch_container" class="clearfix">
<div id="sf_ch_formtitle">SEARCH </div>
 <div id="sf_ch_stype"> SEARCH</div>
     </div>
     <div class="stype">
      <input name="text"  class="search-input" type="text" value="key"  size="20" maxlength="50" />
    </div>
    <div class="stype" >
      <input name="text2"  class="search-input" type="text" value="key"  size="20" maxlength="40" />
    </div>
    <div class="stype" >
      <input name="text2" class="search-input" type="text" value="key"  size="20" maxlength="40" />
    </div>
    <div class="stype" >
      <input name="text2" class="search-input" type="text" value="key"  size="20" maxlength="40" />
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

If you run the code in Firefox or Chrome press F12 and watch the height of the body tag and of the first div after the body, you will see that none have dynamically changed their height to include the inner content.

I don't know where the problems is in the CSS.

And a second problem, if you make a preview  using IE v.6 you will see that all the input fileds are disorder wich I don't understand why??

Any help will be much appreciated!!

Comment: please set up a jsfiddle.net, for example...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since #searchform is absolutely positioned, its parents will have a height of 0. You can try:

```
body, body>div{min-height:100%;}
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jEfMx/